# Woocommerce Remove all Items from cart on New Session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm want to clear all items in cart when a new session is started. I've tried

```
add_action( 'init', 'clear_cart_on_it' );
function clear_cart_on_it() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
 }
```

It is throwing this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function empty_cart() on null in /home/shuggapa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/candy-scoops/scoops.php on line 53
```

I have no idea why. Please how can I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @"Vidish Purohit"'s answer, you want to additionally confirm the referer, and use a more suitable hook.

On the page initiating the delete, use:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="empty_cart">
    <?php wp_nonce_field("empty_cart", "empty_cart"); ?>
    <button type="submit">Remove all</button>
</form>
```

To handle the delete, add this hook in your functions:

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'my_woocommerce_init');
function my_woocommerce_init() {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] === "empty_cart") {
        wp_verify_nonce("empty_cart", "empty_cart");
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

First it checks that the submit happened (`$_POST['action']` present and matching), then `wp_verify_nonce` checked that the POST really was initiated from a reliable origin.

And most essentially, the `woocommerce_init` hook makes sure the global `WC()` returns something to work with.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, init hook is triggered before Woocommerce object is instantiated. You can use this hook:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'clear_cart_on_it' );
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'clear_cart_on_it' );
```

Comment: `woocommerce_init` seems to be the appropriate [hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WooCommerce.html#446).